# Executing process with process.start causes memory segfault but starting manually in shell does not

Tags: c#, shell, dotnet-linux

I'm attempting to use C# to wrapper a linux executable that needs some hand holding of error and conditions. I am doing this inside a docker container and calling my C# app as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

My C# application is properly starting up on container start and goes to start the sub-process but the sub-process errors out every single time it boots with the following.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

If i remove my C# wrapper service and directly call the sub-process from `./entrypoint.sh` it boots up just fine.

I've been up/down and all over the place but i can't find anything about `process.start` that could be creating a different start environment than a standard shell start.

I've tried directly executing the process, executing the process as a `/bin/sh -c "myproc"`, and `/bin/sh /app/entrypoint.sh`. No matter what happens, if it is started by `process.Start()` it will crash, if its started via the shell it will be fine.

Here is my process start code.

```
_process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/sh",
                    Arguments = "/app/entrypoint.sh",
                    WorkingDirectory = "/app",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
```

My `entrypoint.sh` is pretty simple.

```
#!/bin/sh
#whoami # returns root
#ps aux # looks fine

exec myproc-server
```

Does `process.Start()` spawn the process in a method that would cause it to not be a full shell?

Comment: Have you tried `UseShellExecute = true`?

Comment: Yep, still causes same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, i had to specify the following attributes.

```
CreateNoWindow = true,
RedirectStandardError = true,
RedirectStandardOutput = true,
```

Once i redirected the output and error it started working.